# How to click on the span element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to identify the following element but no matter the method it doesn't see it.

```
<span onclick="onClickTab('details'); return false;" id = "details" name = "details" class style ="display: inline;"">...</span>
```

I've tried with: `Xpath, relative xpath, onclick, onclick contains, by id, by name,` just nothing works.
It is a clickable button which appears after selecting an item in a list.

Current code is:

```
try:
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[@onclick='onClickTab('details'); return false;']")))
except
print("Error")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@onclick='onClickTab('details'); return false;']").click()
```

if there are any minor syntax problems like a "(" or such it might be because I typed it by hand, that shouldn't be the issue.
I'm forever grateful if you could point me to the right direction.

Comment: You should be able to ask the browser what the button's exact xpath is.  Usually this is done by right-clicking the button and choosing "inspect".

Comment: It's the only place in the webpage where I can't right click. I have gone through the code to find that reference to it.

Comment: I've also tried with the devtools CTRL+Shift+C and going to the element.  Neither css selector nor the xpatjh are working. The same error is given: " Unable to locate element"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to select the element using the following xPath:

```
//span[contains(@onclick, "onClickTab(\'details\'); return false;")]
```

Using selenium, I used:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//span[@onclick="onClickTab(\'details\'); return false;"]')))
except:
    print("Error")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@onclick="onClickTab(\'details\'); return false;"]').click()
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( . I've tried every possible combination. I was  able to acces every element until now but this one. Could it be something that is locked into a frame? But I think I did select the frame of the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the `<span>` element instead of `presence_of_element_located()` you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#details[name='details'][onclick^='onClickTab']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='details' and @name='details'][starts-with(@onclick, 'onClickTab')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here i suggest you to use id in Xpath.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@id,'details')]").click()
```

if multiple element is there then you have to use foreach loop of `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@id,'details')]")` and check with text and click on match element.